# Module redirects : replacement character for parameter in query string

Tags: redirection

I need to redirect old URLs that have parameters like

```
/my-page?page=1
/my-page?page=2
```

I thought I could use the [urls redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) to indicate a url with a replacement character but that doesn't work. If I redirect `/my-page?page=1` to `/new-page` it works but I would have liked to make a source url that works in all cases.

I tested for example :

```
/my-page?page=*
/my-page?page=.*
/my-page?page=(.*)
/my-page\?page=.*
```

And it doesn't work. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Did you try `/my-page`? See also https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/3352116 and https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/3295924

Comment: @cilefen In this case, the redirect module removes the character `?` I also  uncheck option: `Retain query string through redirect` to not have the query in the destination url. Redirect module consider that `my-page` and `my-page?` are the same.

Comment: Some years ago I used https://www.drupal.org/project/regex_redirect for a large migration, converting query params to node IDs. The module seems to be unmaintained though, can't see a recent D10 version :-( But there is a dev branch with D10 support, don't know the status of that.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel I thought that is what you want. Perhaps the Question needs more information.